# iBeacon and WatchO2: does CoreLocation run from the Watch or the iOS device?

Tags: ios, ibeacon, proximity, watchos-2, watchos

Does WatchO2 CoreLocation run from the Watch or the iOS device?

I have made a sample app using WatchOS 1 and an iOS 8 device and noticed that the CoreLocation data that I was getting from the **watch extension** to get the proximity with the iBeacon **seemed to be deriving from the iOS device** (when I get the Watch closer to the iBeacon the proximity data does not change anything, but instead it changes when I get the iOS device closer or further away). However **with the introduction of WatchOS 2 I would want to get the proximity from the watch and not the iOS device**.

Is this possible in **watch os 2**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth seem not to be available directly from the WatchOS 2. So the answer to my question is **no** due to API limitations.

Please comment if otherwise.

There is the possibility to use the connectivity framework to access the phone data, but it is a different design from the one I was after (direct access to watch BLE hardware)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that with the watchkit preview released at WWDC 2015, using CoreLocation to range for beacons  on the watch itself is now possible.  I have not tested this myself yet, so I will defer to others on details.